# ORs and AND in if statement in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-expression

I am trying to make an if statement which executes when one of the criteria are fulfilled AND two variables are less than or greater than a specific number:

```
if (
    (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or 
    (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT) or
    (row == 12)
   ) and ((row > 5) and (col < 6)):
```

When using this code the or statements work but when it gets to the AND part, if row is less than 5 and col is less than 6 it will go to the else part of the statement. I would like it so that the statement only goes to the else if row is less than 5 and col is larger than 6.

Comment: When you say "*only* goes to the else if row<5 and col>6"  it's a little ambiguous, but that makes it sound like you should be using `or` instead of `and` at the top level (between the two sets of conditions).  Might help to debug the logic if we had some more context of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT) or (row == 12)):
    if ((row > 5) and (col < 6)):
       exec_func();
```

Usually you would try to avoid having too much going on on each row, as it makes it harder to see whats happening and to reason about what it leads to.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
if ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or 
(opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT) or (row == 12)) and 
((row > 5) or (col < 6)):
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd move the row and colum test to the front; you can simplify the `opponentBoard` test:

```
if row >= 5 and col <= 6 and (row == 12 or opponentBoard[row][col] in (const.MISSED, const.HIT):
```

So *three conditions* must be met here:

- The row is 5 or greater
- The column is 6 or lower
- One of:

  - The row is number 12
  - The board cell contains a `MISSED`
  - The board cell contains a `HIT`

In all other cases, the condition is not met and the `else` suite is executed.

Note the use of `>=` and `<=` here!

If you visualise this in a grid, the `if` statement only applies to the cells marked with `x`:

```
┌─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┬─┐
│ │0│1│2│3│4│5│6│7│
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│0│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│1│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│2│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│3│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│4│ │ │ │ │ │ │ │ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│5│x│x│x│x│x│x│x│ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│6│x│x│x│x│x│x│x│ │
├─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┼─┤
│7│x│x│x│x│x│x│x│ │
└─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┴─┘
```

and the `else` statement will apply to everything else *or* if the `x`-ed area if there is no `HIT` or `MISS` in the cell, with the exception of row 12.

If you wanted the `else` suite to only ever apply to the cells not marked with `x`, *regardless of their state*, then you need to split out the tests:

```
if row >= 5 and col <= 6:
    if row == 12 or opponentBoard[row][col] in (const.MISSED, const.HIT):
        # do something
else:
```

Comment: `The statement only goes to the else if row is less than 5 and col is larger than 6.`  In your example, if row = 3 and col = 3, the else clause would be executed (but maybe shouldn't).  I think the operator needs to clarify what he wants exactly.

Comment: @Gerrat: it is not clear that the OP understands the requirements all that well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have your comparisons in the wrong direction. Try `(row < 5) and (col > 6)`.

When writing complicated boolean logic like this I like to split it up into separate variables, e.g.

```
# tried to make up appropriate names but not sure how accurate they really are
cell_is_used = ((opponentBoard[row][col] == const.MISSED) or 
    (opponentBoard[row][col] == const.HIT) or
    (row == 12))

cell_in_bounds = row < 5 and col > 6

if cell_is_used and cell_in_bounds:
    # do your stuff...
```

I like this form because in  a debugger I can view the different sub-expressions and make sure they're doing what I think they're doing. It's also a little easier to read and make sense of; sometimes I notice errors I've made simply by trying to name the different parts of my boolean expression.